# Rretrieving data from foreign key, One to One Relationship. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to retrieve value from foreign key table with one to one relation. I have defined two models:
1. Blog

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'blogs';

    public function blog_category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Blog_Category');
    }
}
```

2. Blog Category

```
class Blog_Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table=('blogs_categories');

    public function blog()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Blog');
    }


}
```

I have got blogs_categoryid in blogs table that has been referenced to id from blogs_categories table.

I have tried following:
{{$blog->blogs_categoryid->category}}

But it is showing "trying to get property of non-object". What is going wrong here? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Blog model content should be:

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blogs';

    public function blog_category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Blog_Category', 'blogs_categoryid');
    }
}
```

Then use `with` when you want it to query relation table:

```
$blog = Blog::with('blog_category')->get(); 
$categoryObject = $blog->blog_category;
$categoryId = $categoryObject->id;
```